# VBA Excel Reading text file from certain line number onward

Tags: vba, excel, text-files, file-read

say we have an external program, that writes a text file during a long calculation.
Now, I need to read that file in order to check the status of calculation (residuals values, stop on error etc).
The file has size of up to 1Mb. Since the program only adds new information to the end of the file, I dont want to reopen it and reread from the very beginning each time.

Is there a way to start reading the file from a specific line number (where I stopped last time)?

What happens to the file when it is opened in Excel for reading, and after that it is changed by the external program? EoF position shifts forward?

Comment: You can't open a file that while is open by other process.

Comment: As far as I understand, the program writes the file or adds last lines to it and closes it. So that I can open and read the file with notepad.

Comment: For pesistence you can handle a text auxiliar status file with the number of the lines processed to that time.

Comment: Of cource. The proble is - when I open the next "updated" file, I dont want to reread all those lines, that I have already analysed.
Is there anything like 
File Input #1, line_number, text_string, where i.e. line_number = 10023?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the statement [Seek [#]filenumber, position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251328.aspx) to move to a specific byte in a opened file. Just save the position in the file where you stopped with the function [Seek( filenumber )](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278614.aspx) or with [LOF( filennumber )](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251466.aspx) if you reached the  [EOF( filenumber )](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251636.aspx).

Comment: And is there something similar in text mode? coz I open it in text.

Comment: There is no "text mode" for statement [Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163.aspx) in vba. Since you didn't post any code, I cannot help you any further.